# Adding a mouse click eventhandler to a PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a picturebox control and upon clicking it another PictureBox appears at a specific location. I.o.w it wasnt added from the toolbox.

```
PictureBox picOneFaceUpA = new PictureBox();
        picOneFaceUpA.Location = new Point(42, 202);
        picOneFaceUpA.Width = 90;
        picOneFaceUpA.Height = 120;
        picOneFaceUpA.Image = Image.FromFile("../../Resources/" + picFaceUpToBeMoved[0] + ".png");
        Controls.Add(picOneFaceUpA);
        picOneFaceUpA.BringToFront();
```

How would I add a MouseClick eventhandler to this control?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just add an event handler using the `+=` operator:

```
picOneFaceUpA.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(your_event_handler);
```

Or:

```
picOneFaceUpA.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler((o, a) => code here);
```

Comment: I find my picturebox doesn't have `MouseClick`?

Comment: @AllanRuin - It does, as do all (or most) WinForms controls: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox_events(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Orz, I found it. Previously I type the picturebox instance in non-contructor part of my class, so MouseClick is not usable.

Comment: what if instead of a picturebox i am using simply an image object?

Comment: @Ashton An image object isn't a UI control; it's just image data. You'll still need to put it in some kind of control to display it on the UI.

Answer (score 2):

Best way in WinForms to subscribe to event - select your control in designer, go to Properties window and select events tab. Then choose any event you want (Click, MouseClick, etc) and double-click on space to the right of event name. Event handler will be generated and subscribed to event.

---

If you want to subscribe to event manually, then add event handler to event

```
picOneFaceUpA.MouseClick += PicOneFaceUpA_MouseClick;
```

Hitting `Tab` after you write `+=` will generate handler. Or you can write it manually:

```
void PicOneFaceUpA_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   // handle click event
   if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
       MessageBox.Show("Left button clicked");
}
```

---

*BTW* if you don't need additional info about click event (e.g. which button was clicked), then use `Click` event instead. It handles left button clicks by default:

```
picOneFaceUpA.Click += PicOneFaceUpA_Click;
```

And handler:

```
void PicOneFaceUpA_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // show another picture box
}
```

Comment: @carny666 changed to MouseClick, but actually if OP is interested only in `picturebox control and upon clicking it `.. then Click should be enough

Comment: Minor comment... You gotta hit tab twice to generate the function. The first tab only generates the text 'PicOneFaceUpA_Click'.

Answer (score 1):

If you type `picOneFaceUpA.Click +=` then hit tab, it will autocomplete for you and implement the event handler:

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PictureBox picOneFaceUpA= new PictureBox();
        picOneFaceUpA.Click += new EventHandler(picOneFaceUpA_Click);
    }

    void picOneFaceUpA_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you know how to add dynamic controls then you should just do

```
this.picOneFaceUpA.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(yourMethodName); //hook
```

and to remove a event

```
this.picOneFaceUpA.MouseClick -= yourMethodName;     //unhook
```

the method should be declared something like this:

```
private void yourMethodName(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    //your code here
}
```